# How to change one or more characters from a string entered into the keyboard in MASM32

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32

```
movzx eax, byte ptr [a]
movzx ebx, byte ptr [m]
add al, bh
```

I used the above command but the program doesn't show anything

I want to change the characters according to the Caesar cipher, that is, the letter a to b,c,d with that change between the number entered in the keyboard for example m=1 then a to b m=2 then a to c

Comment: All the code you've posted does is read two values from memory and adds them together. We have no idea why _"the program doesn't show anything"_ since you haven't shown us any code that would generate output that the user could see.

Comment: Also, `bh` will always be zero at the point where you do `add al,bh`, since you used `movzx ebx`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> add al, bh
> ```
>
> I used the above command but the program doesn't show anything

You don't actually output anything to a screen, so I understand that you are using the word 'show' loosely here, in the sense that the addition `add al, bh` simply does not change the AL register.
The reason for this is that the BH register is zero because of the `movzx ebx, byte ptr [m]` instruction. So it is a typo and what you meant to happen is adding **BL** to AL. And because you are writing 32-bit code, that would better become `add eax, ebx`:

```
; Caesar cipher loop
    movzx ebx, byte ptr [m]  ; CONST
.a: movzx eax, byte ptr [a]  ; Current character
    add   eax, ebx
    cmp   eax, "z"
    jbe   .b
    sub   eax, 26
.b: mov   byte ptr [a], al
    ...
```